# FB Prophet sub-daily data - trend is captured, but hourly seasonality is not

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-prophet

I've been trying to use FBProphet to train a model with historical hourly data and forecast at an hourly frequency for the next 5 days. I see that the trend is captured somewhat, but the hourly data variation is not at all captured. Could anyone please advise what settings may help capture this variation?

Training and test data with corresponding predicted values are as seen [image: here].